# This happened to me or with me

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between *happened **to** me* and *happened **with** me*?

How can I use them in different situations  ?

Comment: What makes you think one is “the right answer” (and one is the “wrong” answer)? Both expressions can be used but they mean different things. We don’t even know what you are trying to say, so it’s hard to say which is the “right” way to say it. You should edit your question and add more details.

Comment: The same question here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3098/expressing-an-opinion-to-me-or-for-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Happened **to** me* is all about telling stories.

> A: The funniest thing happened to me yesterday! I was at the grocery store and. . .
>
> B: Yes, that happened to me once too!

They don't have to be in the past, but they need to be about *personal* experience.

> I saw what happened to Jim after his grades slipped. I don't want that to happen to me.

*Happened **with** me* is about what you saw.

> I can't believe what Elise and Jim did! I never thought that would happen with me there.

It's about you *being* in a place, not necessarily about your *experience* with the place. You aren't trying to tell a story.

> This project is going to happen with me leading it! I am sure of it.